# Какой вариант пунктуации правильный?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие, обобщающее-слово

1. Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества: труд, деньги, свобода, семья, – определяют модели поведения его граждан.
2. Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества – труд, деньги, свобода, семья, – определяют модели поведения его граждан.
3. Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества: труд, деньги, свобода, семья – определяют модели поведения его граждан.
4. Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества – труд, деньги, свобода, семья – определяют модели поведения его граждан.

Comment: меня опять ставят в тупик твои-ваши выборы сочетания слов: общества - граждане? граждане культуры индустриального общества? ценности культуры - деньги? или свобода? в общем какой-то салат-винегрет. ценности культуры индустриального общества труд деньги свобода семья модели поведение граждане - на 11 понятий, один псевдоглагол "определяют", одно прилагательное general - главные и 1 местоимение. Это нечеловеческий текст.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Варианты с запятой отпадают. При её постановке нарушается связь между подлежащим (каким бы оно ни было) и сказуемым.
Выбор двоеточия или тире после первой части предложения определяется отношениями в группе подлежащего, а также структурой и интонацией в контексте.
Двоеточие вполне подходит в предложении без продолжения:

*Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества: труд, деньги, свобода, семья.*

В исходном же предложении интонационное предупреждение с понижением тона, характерное для двоеточия, не звучит. Наоборот, тон после "главного" подлежащего (*ценности...*) повышается и переходит на однородный ряд, выступающий в роли приложения и читающийся со вставочной интонацией.

Я выбираю **4-й вариант**:

*Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества – труд, деньги, свобода, семья – определяют модели поведения его граждан.*

> **10.** Если находящаяся в середине предложения группа однородных членов, стоящих после обобщающего слова, имеет характер уточнения или может быть приравнена к обособленным приложениям, то она с обеих сторон выделяется **тире**: *Всё это — **звуки** и **запах, тучи** и **люди** — было странно красиво и грустно* (М. Г.); *В четырёх городах Италии — **Риме, Неаполе, Турине** и **Милане** — приняла старт финальная часть футбольного чемпионата Европы* (Газ.); *Все присутствующие — **делегаты** и **гости** — внимательно слушали докладчика.*

[Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103) (Розенталь)

Comment: Я думаю, вы оба правы. Если мы выбираем 3-й, то мы эти вещи – ценности-то общества – акцентируем. Если мы 4-й берём, то мы эти ценности выносим как второстепенное перечисление их.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр, акценты могут быть расставлены по-разному. Если мы хотим сделать акцент на перечислении, мы грубо напишем так:  "Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества: труд, деньги, свобода, семья. Они определяют модели поведения его граждан". А вот выделение этого ряда с двух сторон тире хоть и выносит на второй план с синтаксической т.з., но с семантической оно может быть вовсе не второстепенным, оно может включать в себя очень важную пояснительную информацию и произноситься не на пониженных тонах и в быстром темпе, а с чувством, с толком, с расстановкой.

Comment: Два тире – это вставочная интонация, обычно – понижение тона, второй план речи.  Ряд исключен из основного сообщения, вот это важно.   А если двоеточие, то мы понижаем тон перед рядом, предупреждая о перечислении. Ряд в этом случае акцентирован. А выбор зависит от контекста (от темы). По нему и будет видно, что важнее и как надо выбрать знаки.

Comment: @Sharon  При двоеточии тон снижается почти как при точке. Тогда смысл соответствует этому: "Главными ценностями культуры индустриального общества [которые определяют модели поведения его граждан] являются труд, деньги, свобода, семья" (или: "Главные ценности... – это труд..."). В структуре исходного предложения двоеточие не подходит.

Comment: @Sharon Второй план речи не обязательно должен быть второстепенным, попутным, монотонным, быстрым. Существует  градация вставок по степени семантической отчужденности от основной части. Первая группа: "вставные конструкции **минимальной степени отчужденности**, содержащие информацию разъяснительного характера (толкование, уточнение, пояснение)".

Comment: Александр, я не сомневаюсь в правильности вашего ответа (проголосовала за него раньше всех). Мне понравилось, что вы обозначили альтернативу обычному классическому решению. Но из двух вариантов надо выбрать тот, который подходит для конкретного предложения. Чуть позже я допишу, как я делаю выбор, у нас немного разный подход.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 3.
*Главные ценности культуры индустриального общества: труд, деньги, свобода, семья – определяют модели поведения его граждан.*

***Правило Розенталя:***

> Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие ***после*** обобщающего слова,
> **не заканчивают** собой предложения, то перед ними ставится **двоеточие**, а
> после — **тире**: Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в оправе, записная книжка,
> часы, фотографический аппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об
> интересном госте?

---

В вашем случае **обобщающим** словом будет слово "ценности", а **однородными** **членами** - следующие слова: "труд, деньги, свобода, семья". Поскольку дальше предложение продолжается, нужно ставить тире **после** **последнего однородного члена** предложения - после слова "семья".

Comment: Я думаю, вы оба правы. Если мы выбираем 3-й, то мы эти вещи – ценности-то общества – акцентируем. Если мы 4-й берём, то мы эти ценности выносим как второстепенное перечисление их.

Answer (score 1):

Я поддерживаю ответ Александра, но хочу рассказать, как я делаю выбор знаков. Полагаю, что решение зависит от **темы всего текста**.

**Тема 1: Индустриальное общество и модели поведения его граждан.**

*Особенности поведения граждан  связано  и с ценностями культуры общества.  Так, главные ценности культуры индустриального общества – **труд, деньги, свобода, семья** – определяют модели поведения его граждан.*

Перечисление ценностей на втором плане, интонация вставочная.

**Тема 2: Индустриальное общество и ценности его культуры**

*Ценности культуры  общества  очень значимы  и влияют на все стороны жизни.  Так, главные ценности культуры индустриального общества: **труд, деньги, свобода, семья** – определяют модели поведения его граждан.*

Перечисление ценностей  на первом плане, ряд встроен в структуру  всего предложения.